# how to calculate change of values over time in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have a below dataframe and want to count the number of time the value got changed over time.

**input dataframe:**

```
class  date         value
A      2019-01-02   80
A      2019-02-02   80
A      2019-03-02   90
A      2019-04-02   20
A      2019-05-02   80
A      2019-06-02   Null
A      2019-06-03   70
A      2019-06-04   70
A      2019-06-05   20
B ...
```

**output dataframe as below:**

```
class count_of_val
A      6
```

reason: (80,90,20,80, null,70, 20)

Comment: The value changes only 4 times and not 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use:

```
(df.groupby('class', sort=False)['value']
 .apply(lambda x: (x != x.shift()).sum()-1)
 .reset_index(name='count_of_val'))
```

[out]

```
  class  count_of_val
0     A             6
```

Comment: I think `cumsum` not neccesary here

Comment: `df.groupby('class')['value'].apply(lambda x: x.ne(x.shift()).sum())` see my answer, `cumsum().max()` is only `sum()`...

Comment: ah good point .. updated thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `diff()` function of pandas-DataFrame

```
df['count_of_val']=np.where((df['value'].diff()).fillna(method="bfill")!=0,1,0)
df['count_of_val'].loc[df['class']=='A'].sum()
```

Output is:

```
6
```

Or if you like DataFrames:

```
df['count_of_val']=np.where((df['value'].diff()).fillna(method="bfill")!=0,1,0)
desired_class = 'A'
df_count = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['class', 'count_of_val'],
                        data = [[desired_class, df['count_of_val'].loc[df['class']==desired_class].sum()]])
df_count
```

Output:

```
      class count_of_val
0       A        6
```

Comment: output is wrong

Comment: Output is not wrong, if you count the changes in value, you have 4 changes, which is the desired output. Otherwise the question has to be edited...

Answer (score 0):

Compute the rolling difference

```
diff_kernel = np.array([1,-1])
df['change'] = df.groupby('class', as_index=False)['value'].transform(lambda s: np.array(np.convolve(s, diff_kernel ,'same'), dtype=bool))
```

Then you can sum it as bool:

```
change_sum = df.groupby('class')['change'].sum()
```

Comment: This is so slow...

Comment: Maybe the native pd.rolling is faster? `df['change'] = df.groupby('class', as_index=False)['value'].transform(lambda s: s.rolling(window=2).apply(lambda x: x[1] - x[0])).astype(bool)`

Comment: this does not work if the values ​​are string or contain the word null

Comment: I think these options are somewhat slower for the sample data framework. With larger data frames they would be much slower